# apache http client

Tags: java, android, facebook, apache

Ok... in my quest for surfing the web programmatically in android. I am finally convinced that apache http api is the way to go. I need some help using it though. I have managed to login using httppost however I would like to be able to continue after that. taking the facebook example again, I login to facebook, now I want to use this login session to lets say post a status, how do I proceed?
this is the code so far(requires cleaning and stuff, it was mostly copied from various sources)

```
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    try {
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("https://www.facebook.com/");
      try{
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

      //  System.out.println("Login form get: " + response.getStatusLine());
 //    EntityUtils.consume(entity);

       // System.out.println("Initial set of cookies:");
        List<Cookie> cookies = httpclient.getCookieStore().getCookies();
        if (cookies.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("None");
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < cookies.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println("- " + cookies.get(i).toString());
            }
        }
       // https://www.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1
         HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost("https://www.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1");

        List <NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList <NameValuePair>();
        nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", "****"));
        nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass", "****"));

        try {
            httpost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            response = httpclient.execute(httpost);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        entity = response.getEntity();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "done",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        System.out.println("Login form get: " + response.getStatusLine());
    //   EntityUtils.consume(entity);

        System.out.println("Post logon cookies:");
        cookies = httpclient.getCookieStore().getCookies();
        if (cookies.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("None");
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < cookies.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println("- " + cookies.get(i).toString());
            }
        }

    }finally {} }catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }finally {
        // When HttpClient instance is no longer needed,
        // shut down the connection manager to ensure
        // immediate deallocation of all system resources
        httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "done",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    }

} 
    }
```

Replace the stars with your email and password and this gets you inside facebook, how do I proceed from there to post a status?

again please don't tell me there is a facebook api, I don't want to use it, the point here is to learn to use apache libraries

Answer (score 1):

The best way to start would be to wireshark and see what a browser is doing when posting a status. Then adapt to it in the HTTPClient.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to keep a session in Mobile Client should be use OAuth, When you get the OAuth Token, you can use the token to use any api that Facebook providers.